# Opengl Shader Program changes state without reason

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, after-effects

I'm writing an After Effects plugin for the windows platform using OpenGL. After initializing and compiling my shader program I call 
`glGetProgramiv(inData.mProgramObjSu, GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS, &size);` and I get back the value 3 (wich is correct because i attashed a geometry shader).
Also I call `glGetAttribLocation` with various attribute names and get back valid values. When my render function is called later, the shader program is completely useless, every call to `glGetattribLocation` returns -1 with the same attribute strings I used earlier and `glGetProgramiv(inData.mProgramObjSu, GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS, &size);` returns a size of 2. I've got a little experience in OpenGL programming, but I never had a problem like that before.
Here is the shader initialisation code:

```
        GLint vertCompiledB = 0;
    GLint geoCompiledB = 0;
    GLint fragCompiledB = 0;
    GLint linkedB = 0;

    // Create vertex shader
    inData.mVertexShaderSu = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );

    glShaderSource( inData.mVertexShaderSu, 1, &inVertexShader, nullptr );
    glCompileShader( inData.mVertexShaderSu);

    glGetShaderiv( inData.mVertexShaderSu, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertCompiledB );
    char str[4096];
    if(!vertCompiledB)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(inData.mVertexShaderSu, sizeof(str), NULL, str);
        GL_CHECK(AESDK_OpenGL_ShaderInit_Err);
    }

    // Create geometry shader
    inData.mGeometryShaderSu = glCreateShader( GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER );

    glShaderSource( inData.mGeometryShaderSu, 1, &inGeometryShader, nullptr );
    glCompileShader( inData.mGeometryShaderSu);

    glGetShaderiv( inData.mGeometryShaderSu, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &geoCompiledB );

    if(!geoCompiledB)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(inData.mGeometryShaderSu, sizeof(str), NULL, str);
        GL_CHECK(AESDK_OpenGL_ShaderInit_Err);
    }

    // Create fragment shader
    inData.mFragmentShaderSu = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );

    glShaderSource( inData.mFragmentShaderSu, 1, &inFragmentShader, nullptr );
    glCompileShader( inData.mFragmentShaderSu );

    glGetShaderiv( inData.mFragmentShaderSu, GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&fragCompiledB );
    if(!fragCompiledB)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( inData.mFragmentShaderSu, sizeof(str), NULL, str );
        GL_CHECK(AESDK_OpenGL_ShaderInit_Err);
    }

    // Create a program object and attach the two compiled shaders...
    inData.mProgramObjSu = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader( inData.mProgramObjSu, inData.mVertexShaderSu );
    glAttachShader( inData.mProgramObjSu, inData.mGeometryShaderSu );
    glAttachShader( inData.mProgramObjSu, inData.mFragmentShaderSu );

    // Link the program object
    glLinkProgram( inData.mProgramObjSu );
    glGetProgramiv( inData.mProgramObjSu, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkedB );

    inData.mPosAttribLoc = glGetAttribLocation(inData.mProgramObjSu, "pos");
    inData.mNormAttribLoc = glGetAttribLocation(inData.mProgramObjSu, "norm");

    inData.mMVPUnifLoc = glGetUniformLocation(inData.mProgramObjSu, "mvp");
    inData.mNormMatUnifLoc = glGetUniformLocation(inData.mProgramObjSu, "normMat");

    inData.mLineWidthUnifLoc = glGetUniformLocation(inData.mProgramObjSu, "width");
    inData.mEdgeWidthRatioUnifLoc = glGetUniformLocation(inData.mProgramObjSu, "edgeWidthRatio");
    inData.mStrokeOverflowUnifLoc = glGetUniformLocation(inData.mProgramObjSu, "strokeOverflow");

            int length;
    int size;
    GLenum type;
    GLchar name[40];

    glGetActiveUniform(inData.mProgramObjSu, 1, 40, &length, &size, &type, name);
    glGetProgramiv(inData.mProgramObjSu, GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS, &size);

    if( !linkedB )
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderInfoLog( inData.mProgramObjSu, 1000, &length, str );
        GL_CHECK(AESDK_OpenGL_ShaderInit_Err);
    }
```

Comment: did you check glError to see where it starts messing up?

Comment: yes, when I try to set uniforms right before rendering

Comment: so I tried calling the shader initialization directly before rendering and this works. that's a lot of overhead though, so there has to be another solution...